# Why does the random number generator keeps repeating the same number?

Tags: c, random, numbers

The goal of this program is to add 6 random numbers into an array between 1 and 50 and there cant be any repeats. I am mostly having problems with checking to make sure that there aren't any repeats.

I have tried multiple things and I just can't seem to figure it out. (There is more code before this that doesn't relate to my problem).

```
..... 
 //puts random numbers into an array
            i = 0, j = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
            {
                    randArr[i] = randNums(1,50);
            }


            //checks to make sure there are no duplicates
            i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, temp = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
            {
                    for (j = 1; j <= arrSize;)
                    {
                            if (randArr[j] == randArr[i])
                            {
                                    for (k = j; k <= arrSize; k++)
                                    {
                                            temp = randNums(1,50);
                                            temp = randArr[k];
                                            randArr[k] = randArr[k + 1];
                                            randArr[k + 1] = temp;
                                    }
                            arrSize--;
                            }
                            else
                            j++;
                    }
            }
.....
//generates random numbers between the inputed max and min
int randNums(int min, int max)
{
        int result = 0, low = 0, high = 0;
        if (min < max)
        {
                low = min;
                high = max + 1;
        }
        else
       {
            low = max + 1;
            high = min;
       }

       srand(time(NULL));
       result = (rand() % (high - low)) + low;

       return (result);
}
```

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` should be called only once at the start to initialized the RNG.

Comment: @Osiris I don't know what you mean. I only have that in the code once.

Comment: But you call `srand` everytime you generate a random number with `randNums`. You should remove `srand` from `randNums` and place it in `main`.

Comment: @Osiris I put srand in main. Did I put it in the correct spot?

Comment: Please don't correct the mistake *in the post*, only in your own code. People won't understand what you were asking. Rolled back. Now it can be seen that you call `srand()` right before you call `rand()` every time.

Comment: It should be at the beginning of `main` as initialization of the RNG. Since I do not see your `main` function, i can't tell.

Comment: Also note that at `temp = randNums(1,50); temp = randArr[k];` you immediatly reassign `temp` so the first assignment has (nearly) no effect.

Comment: @Osiris that makes sense. that was dumb on my part. I fixed it in my code on my laptop by saying temp = randNums(1,50); randArr[k + 1] = temp; but I am not getting anything to print out in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Several observations:

1. You need to call srand() (which you're doing)
2. You should call srand() only *ONCE* (you're calling it multiple times)
3. Values returned by rand() can repeat.  You need to account for that.
4. Bear in mind that the C library uses a "pseudo-random" algorithm - it isn't truly "random".

Also look here:

> https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pseudo_002dRandom-Numbers.html#Pseudo_002dRandom-Numbers
>
> The numbers generated are not truly random; typically, they form a
>   sequence that repeats periodically, with a period so large that you
>   can ignore it for ordinary purposes. The random number generator works
>   by remembering a seed value which it uses to compute the next random
>   number and also to compute a new seed.
>
> ...
>
> You can obtain repeatable sequences of numbers on a particular machine
>   type by specifying the same initial seed value for the random number
>   generator. There is no standard meaning for a particular seed value;
>   the same seed, used in different C libraries or on different CPU
>   types, will give you different random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Every call to `randNums` calls `srand` with the current system time as an argument.

The `rand` function does something along these lines (pseudocode):

```
rand()
{
     seed = (some permutation on seed);
     return seed%RAND_MAX;
}
```

`srand` changes the state of `seed`, which is accessed by `rand`, to whatever you passed as your argument. If your calls to `randNums` occur within the same second, they will both change the seed to the same value, so `rand` has the same `seed` in both cases and produces the same result.